# assigning dynamic id to bootstrap accordion asp-classic

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to use the collapsable accordion panel, and populate it from a database, but don't know how to change the panel id for each panel.

This is the relevant code (I think - not a coder)

```
<% i = 1 %>
<% WHILE NOT objRS.EOF %>
<div aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix" id="headingOne" role="tab">
            <div class="col-md-8 fz-2">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
            <%=objRS("data")%><br>
            <a aria-controls="collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button">
            <%=objRS("titolo")%>
            </a>
            </h4>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 fz-2">
            <% IF LEN(objRS("idchiave")) > 1 THEN %>
                    <img class="img-responsive" name="img" src="public/<%=objRS("idchiave")%>" />
                <% ELSE %>
                    (No Foto)
                <% END IF %>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div aria-labelledby="headingOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapseOne" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="fz-gallery-wrap">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<% i = i + 1 %>
<% objRS.MoveNext %>
<% WEND %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the accordion outside of your while...wend loop, then add your variable `i` wherever the word "One" appears, so that each panel gets unique identifiers.

```
<% i = 1 %>
<div aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
<% WHILE NOT objRS.EOF %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix" id="heading_<%=i %>" role="tab">
            <div class="col-md-8 fz-2">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
            <%=objRS("data")%><br>
            <a aria-controls="collapse_<%=i %>" aria-expanded="true" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_<%=i %>" role="button">
            <%=objRS("titolo")%>
            </a>
            </h4>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 fz-2">
            <% IF LEN(objRS("idchiave")) > 1 THEN %>
                    <img class="img-responsive" name="img" src="public/<%=objRS("idchiave")%>" />
                <% ELSE %>
                    (No Foto)
                <% END IF %>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div aria-labelledby="heading_<%=i %>" class="panel-collapse collapse<% If i = 1 Then %> in<% End If %>" id="collapse_<%=i %>" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="fz-gallery-wrap">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<% i = i + 1 %>
<% objRS.MoveNext %>
<% WEND %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think you should edit your answer by moving the closing </div> after <% WEND %>, as I tried it before, and the page would display messed up, when moved it after <% WEND %> it looks as expected. There is a problem however with the panels being all open when loading the page (they close when double clicking on a panel), do you think is related, or is some other issue? You can see it here www dot fioriera dot com/new/galleria-foto.asp

Comment: You are right about the ckosing DIV. Thank you to the person who fixed that for me. To only open the first panel you need to only apply the "in" class when i = 1. I have updated one line in my answer (`<% If i = 1 Then %> in<% End If %>`).